# Java ConcurrentMap - Position of Key in Map

Tags: java, treemap, fifo

I have an interesting problem I would like some help with.   I have implemented a couple of queues for two separate conditions, one based on FIFO and the other natural order of a key (ConcurrentMap).  That is you can image both queues have the same data just ordered differently.   The question I have (and I am looking for an efficient way of doing this) if I find the key in the ConcurrentMap based on some criteria, what is the best way of finding the "position" of the key in the FIFO map.  Essentially I would like to know whether it is the firstkey (which is easy), or say it is the 10th key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the precise position, or just an approximation? Also, do you ever re-insert the same data/key?

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, approximation would be okay actually.  Any thoughts?  No, I don't need to re-insert the same key.

Comment: @Alan Depth-limited search if the underlying structure is a variation of a search tree or a skip list.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify just a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like the code below will do the job. I've left the implementation of element --> key as an abstract method. Note the counter being used to assign increasing numbers to elements. Also note that if `add(...)` is being called by multiple threads, the elements in the FIFO are only loosely ordered. That forces the fancy `max(...)` and `min(...)` logic. Its also why the position is *approximate*. First and last are special cases. First can be indicated clearly. Last is tricky because the current implementation returns a real index.

Since this is an approximate location, I would suggest you consider making the API return a `float` between `0.0` and `1.0` to indicate relative position in the queue.

If your code needs to support removal using some means other than `pop(...)`, you will need to use approximate size, and change the return to `((id - min) / (max - min)) * size`, with all the appropriate `int` / `float` casting & rounding.

```
public abstract class ApproximateLocation<K extends Comparable<K>, T> {

    protected abstract K orderingKey(T element);

    private final ConcurrentMap<K, Wrapper<T>> _map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<K, Wrapper<T>>();
    private final Deque<Wrapper<T>> _fifo = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Wrapper<T>>();
    private final AtomicInteger _counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public void add(T element) {
        K key = orderingKey(element);
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>(_counter.getAndIncrement(), element);
        _fifo.add(wrapper);
        _map.put(key, wrapper);
    }

    public T pop() {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = _fifo.pop();
        _map.remove(orderingKey(wrapper.value));
        return wrapper.value;
    }

    public int approximateLocation(T element) {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = _map.get(orderingKey(element));
        Wrapper<T> first = _fifo.peekFirst();
        Wrapper<T> last = _fifo.peekLast();
        if (wrapper == null || first == null || last == null) {
            // element is not in composite structure; fifo has not been written to yet because of concurrency
            return -1;
        }
        int min = Math.min(wrapper.id, Math.min(first.id, last.id));
        int max = Math.max(wrapper.id, Math.max(first.id, last.id));
        if (wrapper == first || max == min) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (wrapper == last) {
            return max - min;
        }
        return wrapper.id - min;
    }

    private static class Wrapper<T> {
        final int id;
        final T value;

        Wrapper(int id, T value) {
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Dilum, this is very neat code.  I am evaluating it at the moment - the reason why approximate is okay, is that I am trying to use the FIFO position as a weighting function, to detect stagnation in the queue.

Comment: Just follow up Dilum, this is now working well (with a few modifications) doing what I want.   thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for accessing the order in a FIFO map. The only way you can do it is iterate over `keySet()`, `values()` or `entrySet()` and count.

Comment: Thankyou - I was concerned that this might have been the cases.

Comment: +1 The positon can change at any time. It can even be remove while iterating so by the time you have determined where the position was, it may have moved or have been removed.  You should treat the order as unimportant or unreliable at best.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a `ConcurrentNavigableMap`, the size of the `headMap` gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: I am not sure that would work, it would give me the position in the Key Ordered Map, but would it give me an index into the FIFO?

Comment: If you have a FIFO implementation that implements this interface... but none in the standard libraries do.